# The Protect method or property is not available because this command cannot be used in read mode.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I use the library: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Word 2016 itself. The program copies the file to the folder C:\temp, the document itself is edited, and then moved to another folder. The program falls off in this piece of code:

```
var newPath = @"C:\temp";
if (CopyTemplateFile(report.Template, newPath)) {
    _app.Visible = false;
    _doc = _app.Documents.Open(tempTemplateFile);
    //_doc.ReadOnlyRecommended = false;
}
else return;

_doc.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection);

if (_doc.ProtectionType != WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection) {
    _doc.Unprotect();
}

deleteTempFiles = report.is_deletetempfile;
FillDocument(report.main);
SaveDocument(report.ReportFileName, newPath);
```

```
The following error pops up on the _doc.Protect() method:
 WordWrapper: The Protect method or property is not available because this command cannot be used in read mode. 
  в Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.Protect(WdProtectionType Type, Object& NoReset, Object& Password, Object& UseIRM, Object& EnforceStyleLock)
       в wrd.routings.lib.WordWrapper..ctor(Report report)  
Void Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)  Microsoft Word
```

What could this be related to? I can't remove the Protect method, because otherwise the program will just drag an empty file. The original file that the program copies opens immediately in edit mode. By default, all modes are removed.

I tried explicitly specifying the "ReadOnly = false" property when opening the file, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have your tried checking if the document is in read-only mode before calling the Protect method?

Answer (score 0):

Use [View.ReadingLayout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.view.readinglayout?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dzh-TW%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm161808429)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) to solve your problem.
The error message shown said the "**read mode**" just is the **View.ReadingLayout property=true**, so you should add this judgment

> if(_doc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout==true)
> _doc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout=false;

or

> if(_doc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout)
> !_doc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout;

before calling the [Unprotect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.unprotect).

That's it:

```cs
var newPath = @"C:\temp";
if (CopyTemplateFile(report.Template, newPath)) {
    _app.Visible = false;
    _doc = _app.Documents.Open(tempTemplateFile);
    //_doc.ReadOnlyRecommended = false;
}
else return;

_doc.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection);

if (_doc.ProtectionType != WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection) {
    if(_doc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout==true) _doc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout=false;
    _doc.Unprotect();
}

deleteTempFiles = report.is_deletetempfile;
FillDocument(report.main);
SaveDocument(report.ReportFileName, newPath);
```